# UI Design - Left Image Border for Content Post

Tags: html, css, image, post

I currently have a mockup I am working off of for a website. However, I need help with a piece of it.

The main content of the page will have posts, and at the left side, will have a border, but initially, it will have a circle (to denote a post). I need to figure out how to do this. Can you help?

**Attempt 1**

index.html

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="side">
                    <img src="assets/img/circle.png">
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <h1>Test</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                Much Wow
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

main.css

```
.col-6 {
    .side {
        display: inline-block;
        img {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    }
    .post-content {
        border-left: 1px solid red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 31px;
        padding-left: 32px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

}
```

**Image of what I want**

[image: post-border-image]]

Result of what I made:

[image: post-border-image-fail]]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to add the code you have tried and someone can help you out. Also you should be able to do this with two background images. Once repeated and one not.

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Here, an code speaks a thousand words

Comment: I have tried doing two images, the circle, and a repeating line, but how to actually implement that method has not been going well.

I'd love to post some code that I have been working with but it isn't anything more than just a bootstrap row and column at the moment until I figure out the best to implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Normally, it is frowned upon to just ask a question on this site asking for people to write your code for you. Generally, ask your question in a way that tells us what you've already tried and where you are going.

We all are developers in some way shape or form on this site and no one wants to do another person's work for them... generally.

Given that you're a new contributor, I thought I'd still give this a crack!

I'd recommend just "boxing" each section out. So rather than viewing the circles as part of the border of the sections, see them as decorations that can be attached to the "post" headings that are a part of your mock-up.

In my example -- which you can take or leave, up to you -- I seperate the post heading from the post section. The post section gets the `left-border` while I rely on a `:before` pseudo-element to build the decorative circle. That way you have the most flexibility with the size of the content while also giving you the desired effect you're after.

Once again, welcome to StackOverflow! Hopefully this is a nice introduction, in your next question be sure to fill us in on things you've already tried rather than a blanket "how do I do this?"

:)

```css
.section {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

.section__title {
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  color: #31a3ee;
}

.section__title:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.section__content {
  border-left: 2px solid #31a3ee;
  padding: 2px 30px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">

  <h3 class="section__title">Post Title</h3>
  <div class="section__content">
    <p>Impedit numquam laborum ut et omnis quasi cupiditate. Fugit numquam quibusdam laudantium placeat. Quod corporis quisquam repudiandae voluptas est.</p>

    <p>Illum provident tempore facere ipsam reiciendis quos ut. Quaerat at eos sint ut sint ipsum laboriosam non. Magni aut occaecati amet asperiores.</p>
  </div>

  <h3 class="section__title">Post Title</h3>
  <div class="section__content">
    <p>Impedit numquam laborum ut et omnis quasi cupiditate. Fugit numquam quibusdam laudantium placeat. Quod corporis quisquam repudiandae voluptas est.</p>

    <p>Illum provident tempore facere ipsam reiciendis quos ut. Quaerat at eos sint ut sint ipsum laboriosam non. Magni aut occaecati amet asperiores.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I didn't even know you could use borders to make a circle.

Also the boxing it out really makes sense to me, I just never thought of it that way. Thank you.

I really do appreciate your help and I have updated my initial post to reflect previous comment suggestions that I have, and I will follow that moving forward.

Appreciate the help, take care!

Comment: It's the magic of the `border-radius` property! Just be sure to hard-code the height and width to be the same, otherwise you'll get stuck with ovals.

If this answer was able to lead you to a solution, go ahead and mark this question as complete!